Include C99 code using the restrict keyword in C++ source
We use extern "C" { ... } to include C header files in C++. This does not seem to work if the C file uses C99 keywords such as restrict. For example:
test.h
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

extern void test(int * restrict x, const int * restrict y);

#endif

test.c
#include "test.h"

int main(void)
{
    int n = 1;
    int m = 2;
    test(&n, &m);
    return 0;
}

test.cpp
extern "C" {
#include "test.h"
}

int main(void)
{
    int n = 1;
    int m = 2;
    test(&n, &m);
    return 0;
}

If we run gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic test.c -c or clang -Weverything test.c -c, the compilation is done silently without errors or warnings. However g++ test.cpp -c results in a error. Similarly, clang++ test.cpp -c fails.
Question:
Is there a portable way to use C99 (or higher) keywords in a header file, and then include that header file for use in C++? Various C libraries make use of the restrict keyword, and it would seem desirable to want to be able to use them in a C++ library. As a simple example, the C version of memcpy (I know the C++ version of memcpy does not use restrict, of course, but this is a simple enough example):
https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy
Please note: Non-portable solutions exists. Such as:
#if defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__clang__)
// GCC or clang
#define restrict __restrict__
#else
// MSVC
#define restrict __restrict
#endif

or something similar. I am seeking portable, standards-compliant solutions.

#ifdef __cplusplus #define restrict #endif . Define away restrict to nothing when in C++ mode.

I tried this to force some unit tests to work, my fear is that this is undefined behavior. Would it not be, since the C source is compiled with restrict, and the C++ source is compiled without it?

What else can you do, when C++ doesn't have a concept of restrict? Mixing C and C++ sources is implementation-defined anyhow.

Fair enough. So for any C99 (or C11 or C23) keyword that does not exist in C++, there is no nice way of using it? extern "C" is mostly suited for C89 code?

@IgorTandetnik: Mixing C and C++ is not implementation-defined because “implementation-defined” is a specific term meaning the C or C++ standard requires an implementation to document the behavior. Implementations may define the behavior of their own volition, and then the casual use of the English term “implementation-defined” is not incorrect in some sense, but we ought to avoid using a specific standard-defined term with other meanings.

Pretty well posed, but missing one thing: The  error messages. This question's pretty cut-n-dried once you've got a bit more exposure to C / C++ interrop, but most of the time the the error message clears things up fast , once again for folks who've seen it before.

extern “C” does not mean “compile this as C code”. It’s about linkage, which typically involves function calling conventions and name mangling. The code still has to be valid C++. Wrapping a C header in extern “C” often doesn’t work; the C header has to be designed for interoperability, and that usually means that it has its own extern “C” directive as well as anything else needed for compatibility.

Make your own (extern C) API (interface) of how you would like to call the "legacy C" code. Then use the appropiate C compiler to build a statically linkable library. Then use that library to build the rest of your project.

@Ryan - The problem is not limited to C-specific keywords, but also involves C-code using identifiers that happens to be keywords in C++. For example, void* new = malloc(100); is perfectly fine C, but will not compile as C++.

First, restrict on a parameter has no effect in a function declaration that is not a definition. Qualifiers only apply to lvalues, and calls to a function pass arguments as plain values. Only in the function definition are the parameters objects that can have qualifiers. C 2024 6.7.7.4 says:

… In the determination of type compatibility
and of a composite type,… each parameter declared with qualified type is taken as having the unqualified version of its declared type…

So, if you want to include a header (declarations only, no function definitions) in a C++ file, you can simply suppress the restrict keyword, as with:
#if __cplusplus
    #define restrict
#endif

(restrict could have an effect in a function declaration if it is inside a parameter rather than directly on the parameter, as in void foo(int * restrict *p);. I do not believe I have ever seen that used in code. If it were present in that way, it would make the C++ altered function declaration incompatible with the C definition.)
Second, even in a function definition, the only purpose of restrict is to promote optimization. Removing restrict from a correct program keeps a correct program, with the _Generic exception noted below. C 2024 6.7.4.1 says:

… The intended use of the restrict qualifier (like the register storage class) is to promote optimization, and deleting all instances of the qualifier from all preprocessing translation units composing a conforming program does not change its meaning (i.e. observable behavior), unless _Generic is used to distinguish whether or not a type has that qualifier…

I have cited C 2024, but this is the same from C 1999 on, except there was no _Generic in C 1999.

The relevant text in the standard is appreciated. For what it is worth, all occurrences in the C source are func(restrict pointer, restrict pointer), so this is suffices for what I am doing.

The "No tricks" approach would be :
Make your own (extern C) API (interface) of how you would like to call the "legacy C" code. Then use the appropiate C compiler to build a statically linkable library exposing your variant of the API. Then use that library to build the rest of your C++ project.
